# DDE solvers in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, delay, ode

Is there a way to interface a C++ or a fortran DDE (delay differential equation) solver with MATLAB? The standard MATLAB function is slow for my application and I would like to have a faster solver.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [MEX-files](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/introducing-mex-files.html). It is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I was however looking for a DDE solver which can speed the whole thing up... From what I tried, I am donot think the dde23 can take a mex function as an argument similar to ode15s?

Comment: @lekshmidharmarajan I don't know that, to be honest. I hope you find a solution in the meantime.